# Is there a way to code a bulk download (zip?) for users to download all attachments on my page?

Tags: download, bulk

My app serves up a bunch of files as links that the user has to download individually.  The customer wants me to provide a bulk download option as well.  I'm using ColdFusion, but can probably use other languages or translate into one I can use.  I mostly likely cannot download a commercial tool to do it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply - I appreciate it.  A coworker found the best answer for ColdFusion.  There's a tag called cfzip that does it all.
https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-u-z/cfzip.html

Answer (score 0):

Use curl - in your case it would be libcurl. This would require C++ bindings.

Create a list of your links in a string or a file that your app would access.

Get started with the curl cli.

See here - https://curl.se/docs/httpscripting.html and here - https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-start-using-curl-and-why-a-hands-on-introduction-ea1c913caaaa/

Once you are comfortable with this, use libcurl linked within your app and download the files using the libcurl API.